# Standalone SpringBatch reading from DB

Tags: spring-batch

Im very new to Spring batch, trying to make a standalone spring batch (Without springboot) that reading from MySql DB and write the results in CSV.

I tried googling and nothing worked out. I also can't get to understand the itemWriter/Itemreader creating are they just methods or classes inherit Writer/Reader? the read/write method what are their inputs/outputs ? I can't get any clear rules about this.

The springBatch can never be implanted without SpringBoot? if no so how?
Why I want standalone Springbatch cause I just want a main method to trigger the job. And I don't want a web app to call a certain endpoint to trigger the job.

The injection works without Springboot or its mandatory for the injection to work?

Also The jobLuncher is it injected or configured by xml files? cause sometimes I got error of jobLuancher is null after injecting it.

MY configuration file is :

```
import com.techtalk.debu.batch.entity.Employee;
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "batchDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "batchTransactionManager")
public class LoadController {


    @Bean
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .generateUniqueName(false).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3311/new");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("12345678908");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    public static void main(String e []) throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(LoadController.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);

        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(context.getBean(Job.class), jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Job Exit Status : " + jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(5, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .processor(new CSVItemProcessor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("job")
                .start(step(jobRepository, transactionManager))
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> itemReader() {
        String sql = "select * from person";
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Employee>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .sql(sql)
                .beanRowMapper(Employee.class)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> itemWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name")
                .build();
    }



}
```

and my pom file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.techtalk.debu</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Batch-CSV-to-DB-Project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-batch-CSV-To_DB-Write-Example-For-Beginners</name>
    <description>Demo project for Beginners to understand Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>

            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

when I run my code I got this error:

> Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Job]: Factory
> method 'job' threw exception with message:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: JobRepository must be set

Also I have some questions:

- reader()/writer() this function should return what? what if I want the reader to read from another DataSource what should I do?
- The data source defining in my application.properties by default is used to save job meta data or to apply the spring batch work?

Comment: I added an answer with a complete example. I hope it helps.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your updates.

Comment: I followed your code and I keep getting this error : No bean named 'dataSource' available

Comment: The sample I shared contains a datasource bean, so I don't understand how you get that error if you follow the sample. Without a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces your issue, it won't be possible to help you effectively.

Comment: I edited my question to put al the code inside

Comment: Your question is about a standalone Spring Batch app without Spring Boot and the answer and all the comments were based on that assumption. But now that you shared your code, it turns out that it is using Spring Boot, which is a different story.

Comment: That's a good point cause in my point of view there is nothing related to spring boot and I think this is where I got this error from. so which part of my code using springboot ?

Comment: I updated my code and the resulting error. it says now "jobRepository must be set"

Comment: The job definition in the code you shared in incorrect here: `new JobBuilder("job")`. This should be `new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)`, as showed in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a standalone Spring Batch application without Spring Boot. The reference documentation contains a [code sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) for that. The javadoc of `EnableBatchProcessing` contains an [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html) as well. You also have the [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples) which are not based on Spring Boot.

Here is a quick example for a non Boot standalone Spring Batch app with a `main` method:

```
package org.springframework.batch.sample;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
        String sql = "select * from person";
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .sql(sql)
                .beanRowMapper(Person.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.csv"))
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .delimited()
                .names("id", "name")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                        .<Person, Person>chunk(5, transactionManager)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .writer(itemWriter())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
                .build();
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(embeddedDatabase);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("create table person (id int primary key, name varchar(20));");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            jdbcTemplate.execute(String.format("insert into person values (%s, 'foo%s');", i, i));
        }
        return embeddedDatabase;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    static class Person {
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public Person() {
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Person{id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

You just need to make sure to use Spring Batch 5.0.0 and have Hsqldb in the classpath.

EDIT: based on question update

> rying to make a standalone spring batch (Without springboot) that reading from MySql DB and write the results in CSV.

I updated the sample to something like what you are trying to do. You just need to update the datasource to point to your MySQL database.

> reader()/writer() this function should return what?

Those should return a type implementing `ItemReader` and `ItemWriter` repectively.

> what if I want the reader to read from another DataSource what should I do?

In this case, you can configure your reader to read from that datasource, as shown in the example above. The datasource could be different from the one storing the batch meta-data.

> CSVItemProcessor is a class implementing ItemProcessor <Employee, Employee> and having the process method but the reader not accepted this code

Your `CSVItemProcessor` should implement `ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee>` and your step should be declared as follows:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
   return new StepBuilder("MY Step")
        .<Employee, Employee>chunk(10) // note the explicit input and output type definition here, which is missing in your code
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(new CSVItemProcessor())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
}
```

Moreover, you need to pass the job repository and transaction manager to the step as shown in the complete example above, something like:

```
@Bean
public Step step(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager) {
   return new StepBuilder("MY Step", jobRepository)
        .<Employee, Employee>chunk(10, transactionManager) // note the explicit input and output type definition here, which is missing in your code
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(new CSVItemProcessor())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. but I want to add one step having a reader, processor, and writer. I don't want to use tasklet.

Comment: The docs and samples mentioned in the answer contain an example of a chunk-oriented step.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more question. based on my understanding Springbatch needs a DB to store job repository, plus the DB that I need to transfer the data from, Im confused on this. where to declare each one? and how to ask spring batch to store the job repo in a map or in-memory DB ?

Comment: in another words:   these props spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username, and spring.datasource.passsord. defining the DB that the spring batch will do the batch on or the DB that Springbatch will use to store the job meta-data?

Comment: The `@EnableBatchPrcocessing` annotation is what configures the `JobRepository` with the datasource (see its javadoc). By default, it looks for a bean named "dataSource" in the application context, like in the example. Now if you want to read or writer data to another data source, you can set it on the reader or writer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I spent days without any working code. :( Is it okay to have a quick chat plz ?

Comment: let me know when we can have a quick chat plz, I really need your help asap plzz

Comment: To be effective, please share your code and update your question to describe your specific problem. Once that in place, we can move on efficiently and I would be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have a question, what about the datasource that I define inside the application.properties file? I still have to define a datasource bean inside the code?

Comment: Hey. I updated my code and the error message. can you plz have a look ? I need your help urgently plz :(