# spring batch 5: how to NOT use the internal spring batch tables?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-3, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am migrating my spring boot spring batch application from spring batch 4.x to 5.0 (this is part of spring boot 2.6.6 to 3.1.3 migration).

In our batch application we do not use any spring batch internal table (that spring batch uses for internal house keeping / status / history etc). On migrating to spring batch 5.0 the usage of these internal table seems to be the default behavior which I think was not the case in 4.x)

My Job Configuration looks like below -

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UpdateAssignedProductsJob {

  private static final int DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 25;

  public static final String JOB_NAME = JobName.UPDATE_ASSIGNED_PRODUCTS;

  @Bean(UpdateAssignedProductsJob.JOB_NAME)
  public Job job(
      @Qualifier(UpdateAssignedProductsJob.JOB_NAME + "_STEP_ONE") Step stepOne,
      JobRepository jobRepository,
      JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener,
      @Qualifier("ArticleFlatFilePublisher") ArticleFlatFilePublisher articleFlatFilePublisher
  ) {
    return new JobBuilder(UpdateAssignedProductsJob.JOB_NAME, jobRepository)
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(stepOne)
        .end()
        .listener(jobExecutionListener)
        .listener(articleFlatFilePublisher)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean(UpdateAssignedProductsJob.JOB_NAME + "_STEP_ONE")
  public Step stepOne(
      @Qualifier("UpdateAssignedProductsJobPagedItemReader") UpdateAssignedProductsJobPagedItemReader itemReader,
      JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
      @Qualifier("ProductItemProcessor") ProductItemProcessor itemProcessor,
      @Qualifier("ArticleFlatFileWriter") ArticleFlatFileWriter itemWriter
  ) {
     return new StepBuilder(UpdateAssignedProductsJob.JOB_NAME + "_STEP_ONE", jobRepository)
        .<Product, Article>chunk(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE, transactionManager)
        .reader(itemReader)
        .processor(itemProcessor)
        .writer(itemWriter)
        .build();
  }
}
```

As you can see the `StepBuilder` is now using `JobRepository jobRepository` and `PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager`, which was not the case in `4.x`.

On executing above job through a `CommandLineRunner` (a temporary attempt), i am facing below error -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774) [spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755) [spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) [spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at com.wayfair.retail.esl.data_manager_job.DataManagerJobApplication.main(DataManagerJobApplication.java:30) [main/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME
FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
WHERE JOB_NAME = ?
 and JOB_KEY = ?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:101) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
```

Clearly Spring Batch 5.0 is referring to it's internal tables, which I want to disable and avoid above exception. How can I achieve this.

I have gone through the [migration doc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide), but this did not help.

> Job repository/explorer configuration updates.
> The Map-based job repository/explorer implementation were deprecated in v4 and
> completely removed in v5. You should use the Jdbc-based implementation
> instead. Unless you are using a custom Job repository/explorer
> implementation, the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation will configure a
> Jdbc-based JobRepository which requires a DataSource bean in the
> application context. The DataSource bean could refer to an embedded
> database like H2, HSQL, etc to work with an in-memory job repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, Spring Batch provided a map-based job repository and job explorer implementations to work with an in-memory job repository. These implementations were deprecated in version 4 and completely removed in version 5. The recommended replacement is to use the JDBC-based implementations with an embedded database, such as H2, HSQL, and others.

This is mentioned in the [What's new in Spring Batch 5](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html#datasource-transaction-manager-requirement-updates) section of the reference documentation. In your case, you need to provide an in-memory data source and use the JDBC job repository with it (which is the default if you use `@EnableBatchProcessing`), or provide a custom `JobRepository` implementation as mentioned in the migration guide.

EDIT: Add example of initializing an embedded datasource with batch tables

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "batchDataSource", transactionManagerRef = "batchTransactionManager")
public static class MyJobConfiguration {

    // Infrastructure beans

    @Bean
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
            .generateUniqueName(true)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    // "Business" beans

    // Add jobs, steps, etc here

}
```

Comment: @Ben - thanks for suggesting in-memory approach. I would like to minimize the effort/configuration/complexity from my end. Clearly from the code i posted, I am using `@EnableBatchProcessing` and am using H2 (my gradle has this `implementation "com.h2database:h2"`) and am using the default `JobRepository` that is passed in to `StepBuilder`.  But the program is failing at a `SELECT` query as the in-memory DB would be empty and will return no results. How can i solve this. I am using the config as suggested by you as far as my understanding goes. Error: `bad SQL grammar`, i don't get this.

Comment: This means the batch tables are not created in H2. This is because with Spring Boot 3, when you use `@EnableBatchProcessing`, the auto-configuration of Spring Batch (creation of tables, automatic execution of jobs at startup, etc) will back off. Therefore, you need to create the batch tables yourself in the datasource used for Spring Batch.

Comment: Ben.. thx.. from the complexity point of view it looks to be simple to go with `@EnableBatchProcessing` and create those tables on start up (if my guess is wrong regarding the least complex path, please correct). Could you plz point me to any resource that captures all the table my code has to create during startup.  Note: our use case is simple and we really don't need those internal house keeping tables, so i would like to take a path that minimizes the complexity so it will be easy to maintain the app down the next several years.

Comment: Ben.. would you please mind helping me explore more about the DDL schema I need to create for the above sql queries to work. A resource/doc that captures this required schema. This is a prod blocker so any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: from the error - i would need minimum of `CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(
    JOB_INSTANCE_ID, int,
    JOB_NAME varchar(255),
    JOB_KEY varchar(255) 
);`  but it will still be nice to know the whole set of required schema.  Or keep trying till you succeed. :-)

Comment: following the errors i did create these objects -> TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE, SEQUENCE BATCH_JOB_SEQ, SEQUENCE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ, TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS, TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT, TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION ...contd

Comment: ...contd but it seem to get complicated at it goes, Now I am facing Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "SE.CREATE_TIME" not found; SQL statement: ...contd

Comment: ...contd SELECT SE.STEP_EXECUTION_ID, SE.STEP_NAME, SE.START_TIME, SE.END_TIME, SE.STATUS, SE.COMMIT_COUNT, SE.READ_COUNT, SE.FILTER_COUNT, SE.WRITE_COUNT, SE.EXIT_CODE, SE.EXIT_MESSAGE, SE.READ_SKIP_COUNT, SE.WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, SE.PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, SE.ROLLBACK_COUNT, SE.LAST_UPDATED, SE.VERSION, SE.CREATE_TIME, JE.JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JE.START_TIME, JE.END_TIME, JE.STATUS, JE.EXIT_CODE, JE.EXIT_MESSAGE, JE.CREATE_TIME, JE.LAST_UPDATED, JE.VERSION
...contd

Comment: ...contd FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION JE
 JOIN BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION SE ON SE.JOB_EXECUTION_ID = JE.JOB_EXECUTION_ID
WHERE JE.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ? AND SE.STEP_NAME = ?
ORDER BY SE.CREATE_TIME DESC, SE.STEP_EXECUTION_ID DESC [42122-214]

Comment: ..contd could you please point me to the ddl schema that creates the required objects

Comment: Here is the schema for h2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql. And here is a complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75337790/5019386. Look how the embedded datasource is created, you just need to point to it in `@EnableBatchProcessing(datasource = "batchDataSource")`. I will edit the answer with the code.

Comment: ben - this did solve my issue.  cool.. tx.

Comment: ben - would you mind commenting on this..  [-how-to-invoke-a-particular-job-from-commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77305299/spring-batch-5-how-to-invoke-a-particular-job-from-commandline)... i checked [5.0.3 docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html) .. there is no hint of this.